# Error in Django model ValueError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting this error on running `python manage.py syncdb` and `python manage.py migrate`

the model was working fine but then I tried to add another model object and on running migrate commond it displayed the error.

So I reverted back to original models.py but it is still showing the error.

my project's models.py is following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Assignment(models.Model):
    main_sub     = models.CharField(max_length="60", choices=settings.SUBJECTS_LIST, default ='sub1')
    add_sub      = models.CharField(max_length="60", choices=settings.SUBJECTS_LIST, default ='sub1')
    deadline     = models.CharField(max_length="60", choices=settings.DUE_TIME_LIST, default ='12 hours')
    details      = models.TextField()
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length="60")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

and on running syncdb output is:

http://pastebin.com/zFp2mz1Z

I have looked up another questions related to this error but nothing helped.

SUBJECTS_LIST and DUE_TIME_LIST tuples:

```
#dropdown for subjects
SUBJECTS_LIST = (
        ( 'sub1', 'Subject1' ),
        ( 'sub2', 'Subject2' ),
        ( 'sub3','Subject3' ),
    )

#DROPDOWN FOR DUE_TIME
DUE_TIME_LIST = (
        ( '12 hours', '12 hours' ),
        ( '24 hours', '24 hours' ),
        ( '2 days','2 days' ),
        ( '3 days','3 days' ),
        ( '4 days','4 days' ),
        ( '5 days','5 days' ),
        ( '6 days','6 days' ),
        ( '1 week','1 week' ),
        ( 'More than 1 week','More than 1 week' ),
    )
```

Comment: Can you add `settings.SUBJECTS_LIST` and `settings.DUE_TIME_LIST`?

Comment: Possibly you are not using list/tuple as settings.SUBJECTS_LIST or settings.DUE_TIME_LIST. Posting this settings will be helpful.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall I've updated the  question with tuples.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? The problem has to do with a field that has a value of empty char instead of a string integer. It's probably during the migration that the error happens, not sure. Is there already data in you database please reproduce the bug and use `./manage.py dumpdata your-app`. Can you also provide the current create statment of the buggy table via `./manage.py dbshell` then `.fullschema` copy/paste only the statment of Assigement` table. Also you can set pdb on by default in ipython_config.py so and then `ipython manage.py sync` will throw you in debug repl

Comment: @amirouche I'm using django 1.8. I deleted the database when trying to fix the error so `./manage.py dumpdata muapp` returns `[]`.

Comment: @vicodin during my tests makemigrations seem to have some bug. Like, it did not migrate the table correctly. `./manage.py dbshell < .fullschema` and `./manage.py sql app` was reporting different things. Did you move from `main_sub = models.IntegerField` to `main_sub = models.CharField`  at some point ?

Comment: @amirouche No, But I added a field `amount = models.IntegerField()` then on migration it displayed the error so I removed that line and tried, again it showed the error so I deleted the database to start things from begining but I'm still getting the error. On running `./manage.py dbshell < .fullschema` I'm getting  `bash: .fullschema: No such file or directory` and on running `./manage.py sql assignment` it returned `CommandError: App 'assignment' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.`

Comment: if your database is sqlite, you can type «./manage.py dbshell» then in the db shell type «.fullschema»

Comment: @amirouche `.fullschema` was invalid so I tried `.schema`. statement for assignment table: `CREATE TABLE "assignment_assignment" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "main_sub" varchar(60) NOT NULL, "add_sub" varchar(60) NOT NULL, "details" text NOT NULL, "timestamp" datetime NOT NULL, "username" varchar(60) NOT NULL, "deadline" varchar(60) NOT NULL);
`

Comment: really it's difficult to tell like so, we should setup a chat session.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough repo.